# PyQt5 QTreeWidget in layout showing an extra column outside the widget

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, qtreewidget

I am trying to write a PyQt5 widget which will be a basic preset manager inside an application. I am trying to use the QTreeWidget to display the structure of each type. I have this weird issue, where I see an extra QTreeWidget with a column named "1" outside my QTreeWidget. I have attached a picture (sorry, I could not take a screenshots) and the code. I have also noticed that this does not happen if I don't use classes.

Here's my test code showing the problem:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyTree(QtWidgets.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(parent)

        boxLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        treeWidget = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
        treeWidget.setHeaderLabels(['Preset Name'])
        treeWidget.setColumnCount(1)
        items = []
        for i in range(10):
            items.append(QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(["item {0}".format(i)]))
        treeWidget.insertTopLevelItems(0, items)

        boxLayout.addWidget(treeWidget)
        self.setLayout(boxLayout)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyTree()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

That's what I see:

[image]

My best guess that it's the layout that's causing it, because if I just create the QTreeWidget like so:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

treeWidget = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
treeWidget.setHeaderLabels(['Preset Name'])
treeWidget.setColumnCount(1)
items = []
for i in range(10):
    items.append(QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(["item {0}".format(i)]))
treeWidget.insertTopLevelItems(0, items)
treeWidget.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

That's what I see:

[image]

Any ideas how to get it showing like the second image, from a class?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is simple: Your window (MyTree) is an empty QTreeWidget that has another QTreeWidget inside, so "1" belongs to the empty QTreeWidget.

There are 2 possible solutions:

- No user as base class to QTreeWidget

  ```py
  class MyTree(QtWidgets.QWidget):
      def __init__(self, parent=None):
          super(self.__class__, self).__init__(parent)

          treeWidget = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
          treeWidget.setHeaderLabels(["Preset Name"])
          treeWidget.setColumnCount(1)
          items = []
          for i in range(10):
              items.append(QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(["item {0}".format(i)]))
          treeWidget.insertTopLevelItems(0, items)

          boxLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
          boxLayout.addWidget(treeWidget)
  ```
- Do not nest a new QTreeWidget

  ```py
  class MyTree(QtWidgets.QTreeWidget):
      def __init__(self, parent=None):
          super(self.__class__, self).__init__(parent)

          self.setHeaderLabels(["Preset Name"])
          self.setColumnCount(1)
          items = []
          for i in range(10):
              items.append(QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(["item {0}".format(i)]))
          self.insertTopLevelItems(0, items)
  ```

Comment: Both methods work! Thank you very much!
I did not notice that using the QTreeWidget as a base class was creating the nesting!